# Textboxes in userform doesnt update after i write data to sheet

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

Update: problem disappears when Column D contains values, and appears when contains formula.

My excel userform contains several textboxes and comboboxes. It is connected with data table on `sheet1`. User for example can type name of project in `textbox1`, press enter and get all  projects with that name from data table in `listbox1`.

listbox results:
[image: listbox results]

After choosing project, user can rewrite data in table by changing textboxes value and pressing button "Rewrite data".

rewriting data:
[image: rewriting data]

And now problem. After rewriting data in data table, clicking on listbox item i cant see any changes. It looks like project that has been rewriting doesnt exist anymore in listbox. But after closing and open userform all works fine. Any suggestion?

problem with userform:
[image: problem with userform]

Full code below. Original file in cloud: [File unprotected](https://yadi.sk/d/l_cIWdIn3ZUMEN)

```
Public Property Get ws() As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
End Property
```

search part

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Dim i As Long
Dim arrList As Variant

If KeyCode = 13 Then
Me.ListBox1.Clear
If ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) <> vbNullString Then
arrList = ws.Range("D6:D" & ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
For i = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
    If InStr(1, arrList(i, 1), Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
   End If
Next i

End If
If Me.ListBox1.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True

End If
End Sub
```

listbox click part

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Dim t As Integer, Lastrow As Long

Dim cCont As control
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
If TypeName(cCont) = "Image" Then
cCont.Visible = False
End If
Next cCont

Me.TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.Value

Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, ws.Range("tbl[Help]").Column).End(xlUp).Row
For t = 6 To Lastrow
If ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Help]").Column).Value = (Me.TextBox1) Or _
ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Help]").Column).Value = Val(Me.TextBox1) Then


If ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Status]").Column).Value = "-7" Then Image4.Visible = True And Image3.Visible = False And Image2.Visible = False And Image1.Visible = False
If ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Status]").Column).Value = "1" Then Image2.Visible = True And Image4.Visible = False And Image3.Visible = False And Image1.Visible = False
If ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Status]").Column).Value = "2" Then Image3.Visible = True And Image4.Visible = False And Image2.Visible = False And Image1.Visible = False
If ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Status]").Column).Value = "3" Then Image1.Visible = True And Image4.Visible = False And Image2.Visible = False And Image3.Visible = False


Me.TextBox2 = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Plant]").Column).Value
Me.TextBox8 = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Name]").Column).Value
Me.TextBox9 = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Code]").Column).Value
Me.ComboBox3 = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Color]").Column).Value
Me.ComboBox4 = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Status]").Column).Value
Me.ComboBox2.Value = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Department]").Column).Value
Me.ComboBox3.Value = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Stage]").Column).Value
Me.ComboBox18 = ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Manager]").Column).Value

End If
Next t

End Sub
```

write data part

```
Private Sub CommandButton51_Click()

Dim lrCD As Long
Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long


With ws
Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, .Range("tbl[Help]").Column).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 6 To Lastrow
If .Cells(i, .Range("tbl[Help]").Column).Value = (Me.TextBox1) Or _
.Cells(i, .Range("tbl[Help]").Column).Value = Val(Me.TextBox1) Then

.Cells(i, .Range("tbl[Department]").Column).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
.Cells(i, .Range("tbl[Stage]").Column).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
.Cells(i, .Range("tbl[Color]").Column).Value = ComboBox4.Text
.Cells(i, .Range("tbl[Plant]").Column).Value = TextBox2.Text
.Cells(i, ws.Range("tbl[Manager]").Column).Value = Me.ComboBox18.Value

End If
Next i
End With

MsgBox "Success", , "Results"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add `Me.Repaint` on the lines before `End Sub` in the subs, which are in the form and try again?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the following line is incorrect, you can't use AND after IF Then like this: `If ws.Cells(t, ws.Range("tbl[Status]").Column).Value = "3" Then Image1.Visible = True And Image4.Visible = False And Image2.Visible = False And Image3.Visible = False` It should be IF... .Then list all your desired changes and then END IF

Comment: Repaint doesnt work. Attach file without password on module [link](https://yadi.sk/d/l_cIWdIn3ZUMEN)

Comment: removed all parts with Image, nothing changed

Comment: Is your `Calculation` Option set to "Manual"?  If so, try adding the line `Application.Calculate` to your "Refresh" button.

Comment: Calculation is automatic. The problem is  - cell values are changed but in userform textboxes and comboboxes nothing happens

Comment: Are you loading the values manually, or using `RowSource`?  If the former, which code-block is reloading your `ListItems`?

Comment: listbox items loading manually according  "search" code-block. It is actually my question - when, where and how insert line with reloading listitems

Comment: @Egor I believe you need *.Show vbModeless* when you pull up your form, so the calculations can occur.  How are you loading the userform?

Comment: Yes, i use userform vbModeless mode. It doesnt affect. Look at my understanding this problem.1 step - after pressing enter in textbox1 listbox add listitems. 2 step - user can click on listitems and see data from table. 3 step after rewriting data we change table, but our listitems are old, cause they can be update only after pressing enter in textbox1. So here is problem.

Comment: If change TextBox1_KeyDown event on TextBox1_Change then everything works ok except one critical thing - i need MultiSelectSingle listbox with bunch of listitems (TextBox1_Change event gives only one listitem in listbox1). So i m stuck here